# socket.io react heroku 405

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, socket.io

I have the following server file:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(server)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3231

const SocketManager = require('./SocketManager')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../build'))

io.on('connection', SocketManager)

server.listen(PORT, ()=>{
 console.log("Connected to port:" + PORT);
})
```

And I am connecting it on the front end like so:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import Game from '../Game/Game';
import axios from 'axios'

const socketUrl = "/"

const socket = io(socketUrl)
```

But I keep getting this in my console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)

I really am not sure what to change or set up to rectify what is an error.

Comment: Your front-end, is it hosted on the same back-end (server file) where you have the socket server on?

Comment: and break this line down and export it separately `const io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(server)`

Comment: they are seperate files, not the same file, I do not think that has anything to do with why the 405 error is happening at all, just the way you prefer it to display based on your own best practices

Comment: I meant to ask are you hosting your front end on the same backend that you have the socket running?

Comment: I am hosting on heroku if that helps, I am also using Auth0 for authentication to log in if that may be messing with something but i do not believe it is

Comment: Does it work on your local setup? and by hosted in same setup I did not mean the online hosting, I mean, how are you running your front end code ? Are you using webpack/other tools to run it? or you are you serving the html file, where the bundle.js is included,  in the same node server that you are running socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My set up was not proper for the people that are having trouble with socketio connection with their backend from a react frontend. This worked for me:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: '*:*'})
const path = require('path')

// for prod dont use port #
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

const SocketManager = require('./socketmanager')

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
  });

io.on('connection', SocketManager)

server.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("Connected to port:" + PORT);
})
```